# Json Parse Error on parsing a hash

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, parsing

I am working on Ruby on Rails. I have a hash like below

```
{"attachment"=>"{:output_dir=>\"/home/mypath/\", :process_hash=>\"8b9d9c51\", :type=>\"pdf\", :processed_dir=>\"/513/9a1/88a\", :pdf=>\"/system/path/a3ae1194f76d737b6cfb141fa0fde17f78f2e94e.pdf\", :slides_count=>4, :meta=>{:swfs=>\"{/system/path/88a/8b9d9c51[*,0].swf,4}\", :pngs=>\"/system/path/8b9d9c51{page}.png\", :json=>\"/system/path/8b9d9c51.js\"}}"
```

In my code i have

JSON.parse(params[:attachment])

which throws me an error as

> JSON::ParserError (757: unexpected token at '{:output_dir=>"/home/path", :process_hash=>"8b9d9c51", :type=>"pdf", :processed_dir=>"/513/9a1/88a", :pdf=>"/system/path/a3ae1194f76d737b6cfb141fa0fde17f78f2e94e.pdf", :slides_count=>4, :meta=>{:swfs=>"{/system/path/8b9d9c51[*,0].swf,4}", :pngs=>"/system/path/8b9d9c51{page}.png", :json=>"/system/path/8b9d9c51.js"}}'):

Suggest me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

JSON.parse parses an JSON formatted String into a Hash, not the other way around. I'm not sure what you'd like to accomplish?

If you're trying to convert a Hash into JSON (string) you could use

> params[:attachment].to_json

If you're trying to convert a JSON (string) into Hash you could use

> JSON.parse(params[:attachment])

However, your string doesn't look like JSON (it includes `=>` where it should have `:`)

Valid JSON looks like:

`{ "attachment": { "output_dir": "/home/mypath", "process_hash": "89r2432" } }`